# Include an HTML/CSS/JS file as code, not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a page that I am using ng-include to pull in a file as rendered HTML. I would like to include that same file as code, next to it.

Is there a way to do this in Angular, or jQuery? I want to be able to include HTML, CSS and potentially JS files as code that would be run through a code-renderer, like Prism or something similar.

This is similar to jsfiddle or codepen, in that you can see the code and rendered view in the same window, but I do not need them to be connected (ie. edit the code to see the rendered result.) I just want to pull both views from the same file.

I am currently using an Angular directive to loop through a JSON file and push out blocks of HTML according to what is listed in the JSON. My directive is:

```
app.directive('patterns', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^ngType', 'ngTemplate'],
        scope: {
            ngType: '@',
            ngTemplate: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'patterns.html',
        controller: function($scope, $http, $sanitize) {
            var theType = $scope.ngType;
            $http.get('indexes/json/' + theType + '.json')
                .then(function(result) {
                    $scope.patterns = result.data;
                });

        },
        controllerAs: 'patterns',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
            scope.getType(iAttrs.ngType);
        }
    }
});
```

And I want to add something that also uses pattern.anchor (based off an "anchor" key I have in my JSON) to grab a particular file and output only the code. I can currently use pattern.anchor with ng-include to output rendered HTML, but not only code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with angular you can use ngSanitize or the $sanitize service.

There's a simple example available here: http://codepen.io/tipsoftheday/pen/jthks

```
angular.module('expressionsEscaping', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExpressionsEscapingCtrl', function ($scope, $sanitize) {
      $scope.msg = 'Hello, <b>World</b>!';
      $scope.safeMsg = $sanitize($scope.msg);
});
```

and a more complex example available in the Angular documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize.

Comment: I am pulling in code dynamically, creating a URL path from a JSON file. How would I tell Angular to grab the code from that file and populate $scope.msg with it, rather than giving it a string as you did above? For example, I would need to tell my directive to "grab the file at folder/{{variable}}.html and place only the code on the page"

Comment: You'd basically need to do an $http.get on the url you want, then run the results through sanitize.

Answer (score 1):

**Ampersand-Delineated Character Entity**

In the code, replace all angle brackets `<` and `>` with a [character entity code](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The entity codes get rendered as angle brackets but don't get processed as such. Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve the *formatting* of your file (read on to see how to do that), since all whitespace gets compressed to a single non-breaking space.

```html
&lt;strong&gt; The strong tag is shown rather
than rendered, but all whitespace characters
still get       compressed into a single space.
However, this <br /> break tag gets rendered rather
than shown. &lt;/strong&gt;
```

HTML provides a block-level element called `pre`. Anything inside the `pre` tag is considered pre-rendered and the browser displays it as-is. Whitespace in this block does not get condensed. This will preserve the formatting of your code.

```html
<pre>
  &lt;strong&gt; In this block, if I add     extra spaces, they are shown.
    If I move to a newline, that is shown as well.
  HTML tags still need to have<br />their angle brackets replaced
in order to be shown rather than rendered.&lt;/strong&gt;
</pre>
```

If you are using JavaScript/AJAX to include the file, you can first do a string replace function to replace the angle brackets with the character entity codes. If you are doing server-side includes, you can do something similar with your server-side language of choice.

If you want to do all of this automatically, Mike Feltman suggested a method using Angular.